# Last-Modified и мобильная версия сайта

Tags: header

Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему

Добавил в хидер сайта отправку заголовков о двте обновления документа,
дата берется из mysql.

Все бы ничего, но вот только у меня две версии сайта, мобильная и десктопная.
И если я первый раз зашел с компа, то получаю код 200,
если после этого захожу на мобильную версию, то получаю 304, и вижу снова десктопную версию, т.к. версия выдается по юзерагенту, но браузер увидев, что страница не обновлялась берет ее из кеша.

Как бы сделать так, чтобы при смене версии браузера с десктопной на мобильную приходил код 200?
Ведь иногда на телефоне включают режим полной версии сайта, а тут это не прокатит, только через чистку кеша ((

Comment: Попытка угадать — `Vary: User-Agent`

Comment: header("Vary: User-Agent, Accept"); ?